# Flexible div layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a layout where I have a toolbar and a main div. When the window Y axis is smaller than window X axis, the toolbar is on the left side. And when the window X axis is smaller than the window Y axis the toolbar is on the top. 
I've positioned the toolbar absolute at the top:0 and left: 0 and tried changing width and height properties on resize. But my code is not working.

Javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
winW = window.innerWidth;
winH = window.innerHeight;   
console.debug("x axis:" + winW  + "y axis:" + winH);

if(winW < winH){
   var elem = document.getElementById('div1');

    console.debug("test" + elem.style.width);

   var a = elem.style.height;
   elem.style.height = elem.style.width;
   elem.style.width = a;

}
else{
   var elem = document.getElementById('div1');

    elem.style.height = elem.style.height;
    elem.style.width = elem.style.width;
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:20px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#div2{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:green;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AjBwx/11/)

Comment: CSS @media queries would do this in a pinch. A _pinch_!

Comment: You should add a unit to it! px, % ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvote for the media ratio ;)

More browser-compatible:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    winW = window.innerWidth;
    winH = window.innerHeight;

    console.debug("x axis:" + winW  + "y axis:" + winH);

    document.getElementById("div1").className = ( winW < winH ? "verticalMenu" : "horizontalMenu" );
}

// optionally invoke window.resize() once manually for setting it default. Or set a defaultClass on the div itself in HTML
```

and

```
.horizontalMenu {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.verticalMenu {
    height:100%;
    width:20px;
}
```

See [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/Eric/pen/zqdik).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { ... }`. Any styles inside this query will only activate when the window is as wide, or wider than it is high.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AjBwx/12/)

I added this code, and removed all the JavaScript:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
    #div1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
    }

    #div2 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
     }                
}
```

Information can be found [here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#aspect-ratio)

Support for Media Queries can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries), but as you can use JavaScript I would recommend using [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to make them work for all users.

Comment: Great sollution! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Just another question. How would I make the div expand vertically to fit the page?

Comment: It doesn't work. The div doesn't get resized. The div resizes only if I enter a value in pixels.

Comment: @Jacob Set the height to 100%, and as long as `html, body` have `height:100%` too it will work, check that fiddle

Comment: Looks like I have a specific case because it's still not working.

Comment: Put it on jsFiddle and we'll sort it out

Comment: I figured out the problem but not the sollution. The content get's opened in a new window. I append the content to the body of a new window. The javascript code makes an empty div in the body where all the content is appended. That div doesn't have 100% height and that is why I have the problem. How to acces this div? It has no id or className?

Comment: @Jacob Set html,body and content 100% height on the new page

Comment: For me this solved the issue: `this.source.body.childNodes[1].style.height = 100 + "%";`
Thank you again for all your help!